# Phinx database migration tool

Tags: php, database-migration, phinx

Phinx is nice tool to database migration and it is working fine with terminal creating tables and seeding data into it by commands, but I want to see some output on the browser from this code before inserting into the tables can anyone help me out how to put some var_dumps in in and see output on terminal or in the browser somehow?

**Example Code:**

```
public function up()
{

    $userLinks = $this->fetchAll('SELECT * FROM user_links');
    var_dump($userLinks);

    foreach ($userLinks as $userLink) {
        $actionPlugin = ucfirst($userLink['action']);
        $actionParams = array();
        $actionParams['UserID'] = $userLink['userID'];

        if (isset($userLink['userSurveyID'])) {
            $actionParams['UserSurveyID'] = $userLink['userSurveyID'];
        }
        $jsonParamString = json_encode($actionParams);

        $this->execute("
            INSERT INTO `token_links` (`linkID`, `token`, `actionPlugin`, `actionParams`) VALUES
            ({$userLink['userLinkID']}, '{$userLink['token']}', '$actionPlugin', '$jsonParamString');
            ");
    }


}
```

Comment: If you run command `phinx migrate -e development` you will see messages from standard output, so you can add `var_dump`, `echo` or even `print` and add die before execution of query

Comment: Great is is being print on the terminal :) But how to show these output on browser?

Comment: How do you run this migration from browser?

Comment: No I don't want to run this migration from browser just want output using this AbstractMigration class, it is impossible to see thousand's of records from loop in the terminal.

Comment: You can add some logging which would be accessible by webserver

Comment: Thank you @alexander.polomodov for giving me some tips. Can you please write your detailed answer so I can approve and it would be also great for newbies like me. Please suggest nice logging tool compatible wtih phinx

Comment: Phinx is not specific with logging. You can use any logging system. For example we prefer `logstash` because it nicely works with `kibana`:) But you can use standard `error_log` php function or just write to file inside one of your webserver directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When [`phinx`](http://docs.phinx.org/en/latest/commands.html) run its migration (e.g. with command `phinx migrate -e development`)all output generated with commands like `echo`, `var_dump`, `print` go straight to standard output.

- So if you run this command from console you will see debug message.
- But if you want to see this message from browser you should use some logging system.

My personal preference to use [`logstash`](http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2//tutorials/getting-started-with-logstash), but you can use standard php function [`error_log`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php) or even write to file which is accessible by your webserver.